# How to adapt this Stanford's C193 function to Swift 2.1

Tags: swift2

How do I write this in swift 2.1?

I am going through Stanford's C193 swift programming class and I'm using swift 2.1.

I want to the user a history of operands and operations on a display a calculator.

It's giving me this error:

> "Ambiguous reference to member 'map'.

```
func showStack() -> String? {         
     return .joinWithSeparator(opStack.map { "\($0)" })     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply `.joinWithSeparator` to nothing, it has to be used on a collection (array for example). And `opStack.map { "\($0)" }` wouldn't make a good separator.

---

The Swift 1.2 version was:

```
func showStack() -> String? {
    return " ".join(opStack.map{ "\($0)" })
}
```

The Swift 2 version is:

```
func showStack() -> String? {
    return opStack.map{ "\($0)" }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
}
```

You just have to extract `opStack.map{ "\($0)" }` and apply `joinWithSeparator` to it (the "joinWithSeparator" method is explained in the new Apple Swift 2 documentation).

Comment: My confusion was because I was inferring from the 1.2 version. Thank you Eric.